# Latex wrap text into figure

Tags: latex, figure

I have one short pseudo-code in Latex manually. I want to wrap it into figure format. I dont want to save this pseudo-code into figure file, then insert to the script.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Is this a picture of your code? Please post the code, so there is something to work with. Preferrably a minimal working example.

Comment: Possibly a hint, using TikZ: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67032/fitting-text-to-a-shape-in-tikz

Comment: Please don't abuse math mode to set whole words, this will completely trash the kerning.